# If $f(g(x))$ is known, then can we find $f(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that $f(x)$ is a parabola, and $f(-2x) = x - x^2$.

Can I assume that $f(x) = -\frac{1}{2}x - \frac{1}{4}x^2$ (real numbers only)?

I got this equation because if I were to plug in $x = -2x$ I would get the original function.

Comment: Title question: No, suppose that $g(x)=0$ for all $x$. Then $f(g(x))$ is known, but we cannot find $f(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general if you have
$$
f(g(x))=:h(x)
$$
and $g$ is an invertible function than you have
$$
f(x)=h(g^{-1}(x))
$$
If $g$ is not invertible then this is not possible. In your example $g(x)$ was linear and not constant and so invertible. and
$$
g^{-1}(x)=-\frac{1}{2}x
$$
as you have found.

Comment: $g(x)=0$ is also a linear function, but not invertible. Indeed, $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$ and $g(\lambda x)=\lambda g(x)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde fixed. I forgot about the zero function

Comment: @JonathanZ constant function are not linear if they are not zero (still your statement is correct as the zero function is the only linear constant function)

Answer (score 1):

We have $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ since it is a parabola. So $f(-2x) = 4ax^2-2bx+c$. Since $f(-2x)=-x^2+x$ we see that $a=-\frac14 ,b=-\frac12$ and $c=0$. This gives us $f(x)=-\frac14 x^2-\frac 12 x$ which agrees with the polynomial you've found.